# mysql update error near '

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have a mysql problem, that i really need help with. My code to the update:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET stock = stock + $quantity WHERE id = $product_id") or die( mysql_error());
```

The mysql_error says following:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
```

Which for me doesn't really makes sence. Btw. all the variables work.

I know i have to update my code, but it gotta work.

Update:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET stock = stock + '1' WHERE id = '1'") or die( mysql_error());
```

That code now works, so it must me something about the variable is a string. How do i make them into a int, i have tried with (int)$variable?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a datatype mismatch. In your database, id is set as an Int. In your PHP code, id is set as a String. This causes problems because injecting `$id` into your query adds single-quotes around the value of id if it is a String. There are two options here:

1. Change the datatype of id in your PHP code to an Int. This may not be possible depending on how your system is designed.
2. Change the datatype of id in your database to a Varchar. I don't recommend this.
3. Change your query. This can be done by concatenating your variables into the query rather than injecting them into the query. The `id` variable, for example:
   `"UPDATE products SET stock = stock + $quantity WHERE id = " . $product_id`

As Jay Blanchard noted, you should look at [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli)

Comment: Okay, i just did intval($variable) to all the variables in the query, but now it doesn't show error or update anything.

Comment: Are you certain that there is something to update? Maybe `id = 1` isn't in the database or `$quantity` is null, adding nothing to `stock`

Comment: Hey, i found out that when i change the variables to int with `(int)$variable` it becomes 0, in each variable. Why does it that, and how do i fix it?

Comment: Are you using `(int)$variable` instead of `intval($variable)`? Please give me some sample inputs so I can see what's going on.

Comment: I've tried both intval and int `$id = intval($_POST['id']);
 $productid = intval($_POST['productid']);
 $quantity = intval($_POST['quantity']);
 $workerid = intval($_POST['workerid']);`

Comment: By sample inputs, I meant the values of the data you are inputting. With that information, I can be more helpful.

Comment: Well, i just found the problem, it tried to print the post array and that didnt show anything, so it turned out that the problem was a variable name. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: Not a problem! Always try printing out the values when seeing abnormal results. Data loves to come in messy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET stock = stock". $quantity." WHERE id = ".$product_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use intval with the quantity, as it may be a string and you're trying to do weird stuff with that:

```
$quantity = intval($quantity);
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET stock = stock + $quantity WHERE id = $product_id") or die( mysql_error());
```

Comment: Hey, i just added all the variables to intval, now it doesnt show any errors, but it doesnt update

Comment: That should be a different problem... as the query is ok: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9969/1

Check your logs to see the output of the error.